# Where to define <Environment...> elements in JBoss

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I try to define environment entries in JBoss 5.1 and added following to the server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/context.xml file:

```
<Environment type="java.lang.String" name="name" value="value" />
```

Following error occurs on startup:

> 2010-01-26 14:50:08,383 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.JBossContextConfig]
>   (main) XML error parsing: context.xml
>   org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException:
>   Failed to parse source: Resource
>   cannot appear in this position.
>   Expected content of Context is
>   unordered_sequence: attributes?
>   InstanceListener* Realm? Parameters*
>   Manager? Loader? Valve* SessionCookie?
>   Resources? Listener*

Where may I define environment entries in JBoss (but outside of application's EAR)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://java.dzone.com/tips/external-configuration-with-jb) confirms that (likely) it is not possible to configure environment entries in JBoss. Author suggests to use PropertiesService as alternative.

Property configuration in properties-service.xml works great!